# knockout subscribe: init or update?

Tags: knockout.js

How can I check during subscription if this is update or init?

I have subscriber that saves value to database. I do not need it to be done when values are loaded. I need them to load only when observable value is updated?

This is how I load my data into model:

```
  ko.mapping.fromJS(dataJson, {}, PortfolioView);
  ko.applyBindings(PortfolioView, document.getElementById(containerId));
```

And this is how I do subscriber:

```
   self.CompanyName = ko.observable();
   this.CompanyName.subscribe(function () {
      // This won't get called on init
      console.log("updated");
   }, this);
```

When page is loading I see updated.

However, in reality I have about 20 variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do nothing. Standard `.subscribe` function doesn't get fired on init.

Try it. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VeDT6/).

```
function vm() {
    this.a = ko.observable("a");
    this.a.subscribe(function () {
        // This won't get called on init
        console.log("updated");
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Actually, the binding I'm demonstrating in the fiddle is `value`. If you're talking about a custom bind, you'll see in the [specs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that the `init` and `update` function are separate.

---

If we're talking about computed observables, as far as I know, the only way to check if it is init is keeping track of the first call with a separate variable. This approach sucks: if this is what you need to do, you're probably doing something wrong. From the example above, we continue:

```
this._isInit = true;
this.b = ko.computed(function () {
    console.log("is init? " + this._isInit);
    if (this._isInit) this._isInit = false;
    return this.a();
}, this);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VeDT6/3/).

---

Since you've updated your question with relevant code, I can deepen my answer. From the [specs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) of `.fromJS`:

> [fromJs] automatically creates observable properties for each of the
>   properties on data.

This is not what you're trying to do. You **already** have your observable and a subscription to it: calling `.fromJS` will change the value of it, causing the subscription to fire. Let `PortfolioView` accept `dataJson` as a parameter to its constructor, then rewrite your code like this:

```
function PortfolioView(data) {
    this.CompanyName = ko.observable(data.CompanyName);
    this.CompanyName.subscribe(function () {
        // This won't get called on init
        console.log("updated");
    }, this);
}
```

Then, calling the following code won't let the subscription fire on the page load.

```
ko.applyBindings(new PortfolioView(dataJson), document.getElementById(containerId));
```

Comment: Probably I do not understand what is init and what is update. Because when I load a page and load data into it, the subscriber is called.

Comment: I first load data into model using ko.mapping.fromJs and then do ko.applyBindings(AView, document.getElementById(containerId));, during binding I have "updated" in console.

Comment: can you show some code? Most likely, you're creating an empty observable, subscribing and then load the data. The data must be loaded WHEN you create the observable. ko.observable(yourData); (if you don't want/can't do like this, then you'll have to create a temporary variable to monitor if is init or update, but this is not necessary)

Comment: I have about 20 or more variables. And I am loading data from json using ko.mapping.fromJS(dataJson, {}, MyView) and then do applyBinding. That is it. So I need 20 extra variables?

Comment: I'm sure there is an alternative approach, but I can do nothing more than guess if I don't see any code.

Comment: I have tried to add code but there is not much to show. Just mapping, binding and your subscription.